# DynamoDB list tables command not returning table

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong, I'm trying to list all tables on my account but the response is different than the sample response in aws's docs. here's my code.

```
const {
  DynamoDBClient, 
  CreateTableCommand, 
  ListTablesCommand
} = require('@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb');

const client = new DynamoDBClient({
  region: 'us-east-1',
});


const listTables = async () => {
  const command = new ListTablesCommand({});
  
  const response = await client.send(command);
  console.log(response);
  return response;
};

module.exports = listTables
```

I'm calling the function in a different file and console log is showing this

```
{
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    requestId: 'E30O4U8REIAK5K5VGP39OHLNCVVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  Attributes: undefined,
  ItemCollectionMetrics: undefined
}
```

How do I get the response to list the tables and not the request status?

Comment: The log you have shown would be the value of the `$metadata` property in the awaited response. It's not the entire response. Add a console.log of `response.TableNames`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListTablesCommand returns a ListTablesResponse object, which contains metadata about the request, but not the actual list of tables.

To get the tables, you need to access the TableNames property of the ListTablesResponse:

```
const {TableNames} = await client.send(command);

console.log(TableNames);
```

The DynamoDB SDK response objects contain metadata in addition to the command result data. So you need to access the specific property that contains the returned data.

```
const listTables = async () => {
  const command = new ListTablesCommand({});
  const response = await client.send(command);
  // Access TableNames property for actual list 
  const {TableNames} = response;
  console.log(TableNames);
  return TableNames;
};
listTables();
```

Comment: Believe the response is of type [ListTablesCommandOutput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-aws-sdk-client-dynamodb/Interface/ListTablesCommandOutput/).